# Why do answers turn blurry when downvoted -3+?

Tags: support, answers, voting

I have saw this before, but now I want to find the bottom of it.

Answers that are blurry I have seen downvoted massively (-3 or more), and a [answer of mine](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/384700/does-the-metal-mario-outfit-do-anything-special-in-super-mario-odyssey/384702#384702) (edited from a comment) became one of them.

Does it turn blurry for the less chance of views, or what?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

According to an [answer](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/166937/913645) from the Meta on Stack:

> SE doesn't just cater to the folks who ask and answer. SE tries to
> cater to those who have a similar problem and find a post via Google.
> Not all non-SE users know what the number [votes] means. It seems obvious, but
> it may not be. Especially for those not familiar with Reddit/etc. **So,
> fading it [the answer] out is a simple visual cue "don't read this".**

Stack does this automatically so users will understand that this answer has been downvoted and is very likely not to be helpful to anyone. It normally happens on questions from new users, as they don't understand all the guidelines of the site yet. But, everyone can still see these answers, and can still comment and vote on them, if they have the sufficient amounts of reputation.

Comment: They can hover the mouse over to the blur and it shows. What about that? Is it locked to specific users?

Comment: No, everyone can see those answers. It just blurs out the answer as a "You have been warned" sign.

Comment: @loan_2314 It's not locked at all. It's only for display purposes

Comment: As I said -3+ downvotes, is it true, how many downvotes does it take for the blur?

Comment: It takes -3 downvotes.